# Why do elements appear outside of the viewbox of the nested svg element?

Tags: svg

In this example:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 400 100" y="20" width="400">
        <rect x="0" y="-100" width="79" height="100" fill="#ff0000"></rect>
    </svg>
    <rect x="100" y="0" width="79" height="400" fill="#ff0000"></rect>
</svg>
```

The inner `rect` with `y = -100` is not cropped despite the inner svg has viewbox `min-y = 0`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

`viewBox` of the svg element does not clip the content, it merely establish a coordinate system[1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute)

To actually clip the content, the `clip-path` attribute has to be used.

Answer (score 0):

In the next example I'm drawing a nested svg which exactly like in your example has a `viewBox="0 0 400 100"` and a width but **no height**. I'm adding `preserveAspectRatio="none"` so that the content of this svg element will be scaled nonuniformely.
Inside this nested svg element I'm drawing a rect the same size as the viewBox: `<rect width="400" height="100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,.5)">`

Please observe that the rect is stretched (because `preserveAspectRatio="none"`) to 400 units height. Apparently the nested svg without a declared height will take the height of the parent svg.

```css
.root{outline:solid; overflow:visible;}
```

```html
<svg class="root"  viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="200">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 400 100" y="20" width="400" height="100">
        <rect width="400" height="100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,.5)">
          <!--a rect with the size of the svg parent-->
        </rect>
        <rect x="0" y="-100" width="79" height="400" fill="rgba(255,0,0,.5)"></rect>
    </svg>
    <rect x="100" y="0" width="79" height="400" fill="#ff0000"></rect>
</svg>
```

This is your example where I've added a height to the nested SVG and a rect the same size as the viewBox:

```css
.root{outline:solid; overflow:visible;}
```

```html
<svg class="root"  viewBox="0 0 400 400" width="200">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 400 100" y="20" width="400" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect width="400" height="100" fill="rgba(0,0,0,.5)">
          <!--a rect with the size of the svg parent-->
        </rect>
  </svg>
</svg>
```